# Animating a directive entering/leaving the DOM in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs and I am trying to create a directive that will always be animated when it is added to the DOM or is removed from the DOM. So whenever the parent of the directive is being destroyed (due to an ng-if or ng-repeat) the destroy should be delayed until the animation of the child (my directive) has finished.

Since there is no ng-if (or similar) on the root of my component ngAnimate won't add a ng-enter or ng-leave class to it. For what I understand I can do it manually using the $animate service.

I probably don't understand how its working, but I cant get it to work.

What I currently have:

```
function myDirective($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        controller: myController,
        template: myTemplate,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $animate.on('enter', $element, function callback(el, phase) {
                console.log('ENTER animation detected', el, phase);
            });
            $animate.on('leave', $element, function callback(el, phase) {
                console.log('LEAVE animation detected', el, phase);
            });

            $animate.enter($element, $element.parent(), null);     
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                $animate.leave($element);
            });
        }
    };
}

app.directive(myDirective, ['$animate', myDirective]);
```

I do get some "ENTER/LEAVE animation detected" log messages but its for some child elements of my directive, not the root element. I also don't see angularjs adding ng-enter or ng-leave classes to my component element.